# Download file popup in IE not working it works well in Fire Fox

Tags: download

location.href, 
 using hidden Iframe and setting its source dynamically,
 setting return false; for onclick 
 Nothing is working for IE.
Basically, my dwr response generates a log file (foo.log) @business layer and it sends file name as response to dwr rpc request. Now I know the file name and its location I just want to download that file.(It works in FF not in IE).

Answer (score 0):

To cause a web browser to download a file that it would otherwise display inline, you must have the web server serve it with the header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
```

Nothing you can do on the client-side with iframes or JavaScript will affect this.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me -- 
Need to write struts action - 
        
           
                inputStream
                application/octet-stream
                attachment;filename=${fileName}
                2048

and action class 
 download examples 
http://jtute.com/codeDownload.html

Struts 2 Design and Programming: A Tutorial chapter 13 a, 13b will give you idea.

No other way we cant set header types in js. we have to action class which will set above mentioned properties.

Comment: <action name="downloadLog" class="com.asterdata.amc.action.FileDownloadAction">
           <result name="success" type="stream">
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
                <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
                <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=${fileName}</param>
                <param name="bufferSize">2048</param>
           </result>
        </action>